# Can someone help solve this discrete maths question?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

[image]

I have an attempt done there and this is the last question I have to do. I'm not sure how to solve
this one. Can someone help me or at least give me pointers on how I can solve this question as
I've been trying for an hour and have absolutely no idea? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Use mathjax please

Comment: c.f. Law of Total Probability https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability. Remark: $P(E \mid A_1) \ne P(A_1 \mid E)$

Answer (score 0):

Here are some facts that can help you figure this out. First find the total probability
$$P(E)=\sum_{k=1}^n P(E\ \vert A_k)P(A_k)$$
Once you find $P(E)$, then you can use it to find the other three answers. Just apply the following three times and you're done.
$$P(A_k\vert E)=\frac{P(E\ \vert A_k)P(A_k)}{P(E)}$$
Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?